# How do you make Eclipse not edit all the occurrences found by "Find Next"?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

When I use `Cmd+K` to go to the next occurrence of the selected word, Eclipse leaves behind these red "cursors" right before the copies of the word that I navigate through. If I then edit the last occurrence that I find, Eclipse "helpfully" edits all the occurrences that I've navigated through in the same way. This leaves corruption in parts of my file that I'm not currently looking at, which is really infuriating.

I want to disable this "feature", but I haven't got a clue what to call it, so I don't know how to find the setting that turns it off. Searching the Eclipse preferences for "occurrence" only gives various versions of "Mark Occurrences" for each editor plugin, which doesn't disable this behavior when unchecked.

EDIT: Here's a video displaying the behavior I'm talking about: https://youtu.be/8xeKRLyGSLg

Comment: This is not the normal behavior, perhaps a picture would help understand what you are seeing.

Comment: I've added a link to a youtube video I recorded, showing the behavior I'm trying to disable.

Comment: So this python? Is it pydev you are using for that? Eclipse can be used to edit many languages and the editors can be quite different, always say which one you are using. What does 'General > Keys' in the Preferences say the key binding is for Cmd+K.

Comment: Yup, it's PyDev. The Cmd-K key is bound to "Find Next" in the Keys preferences. I believe it's also bound to a second thing in a different context, but I don't really know how contexts work in Eclipse, and I'm pretty sure it's also "Find Next".

Comment: I guess this is something specific to pydev which I don't know anything about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really given by PyDev, it's a feature added by LiClipse (http://www.liclipse.com/multi_edition_video.html).

After the link is done with Ctrl+K, you can press ESC to remove those links if you don't want the multi-edition to happen (so that when you edit one occurrence you don't edit the others).

I must say this is the first request to have that turned off... I'm pretty certain as I just took a look and there's no setting to do that -- so, unfortunately, until the next release, you have to either live with it, remembering to press ESC if you don't want the multi edition to happen or use a plain Eclipse install with PyDev, but you'd also be without other LiClipse benefits, such as textmate bundles, vertical indent guides, theming integration, etc.

Still, note that ideally, I'd say you should get used to it as it can be a real time-saver -- although I'll implement the setting to turn it off for the next release anyways, as it's something that should really be there ;)

Comment: It would be a time-saver if I actually used Ctrl-K to do multi-replacement, but I basically never do. I almost always use it for "find other uses of this variable/class/method in this file", frequently to go from a use of the name to the definition of the name. As for Liclipse, I already use it, and like it well enough. It has some minor faults, but is otherwise a solid IDE. I look forward to the next release, which I hope will add that option, and perhaps fix the minor display issues I've posted about in the issue queue.